# Why calling a function through bracket notation

Tags: javascript

I've the following code:

```
function hi(){
alert("hi");
}

window["hi"]();
```

I thought the `hi` will be executed. Is there anything similar, that I could do? (no eval please)

### Edit:

I want it in bracket notation as the function names will be in string.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Actually, your code works and the alert dialog is displayed. What's the problem?

Comment: So what's the problem? `window["hi"]()` will work if that declaration is made at the global level. If not, then it's impossible.

Comment: you could store the functions whose call you'd like to indirect in any  array or object, not necessarily the window: `function ho () { alert("hi ho!"); } var ind={}; ind["hi"] = ho; (ind["hi"])();` should work though.

Comment: My theory is that you tried that code in JSFiddle. Try configuring the code to run in the head element. Doing this will define `hi` in the global scope (`window`). If it is running `onLoad` the `hi` function will be defined within the `onLoad` function.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - That was my though as well, as it won't work like that in jsFiddle with the default options, as the DOM ready function creates a new scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't work, you're probably in the wrong scope, try

```
window.hi = function(){
    alert("hi");
}

window["hi"]();
```

#### EDIT:

If testing in jsFiddle, the default option of `onLoad`, or the `onDomReady` option inserts an event handler that waits for DOM ready with a callback.

The callback function creates a new scope, so when adding properties to the window object you have to reference it specifically with `window.prop`, just typing `prop` is not enough as it's not in the right scope.

Comment: I think you should update your answer regarding jsfiddle, so that I could accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it directly:

```
hi();
```

Or

```
window.hi();
```

if you really want to involve the global object.

*edit* if you *want* to access the function by a dynamic name, then you certainly can, but the function **must** be accessible as a property of some object. The global object is one possibility:

```
function hi() {
  alert("hi");
}

window.hi = hi;
```

Then `window["hi"]()` will work. Alternatively, you can create an object for the purpose:

```
var functionRegistry = {}

function hi() {
  alert("hi");
}

functionRegistry.hi = hi;
```

Then `functionRegistry["hi"]()` will work.